# onCreate method in SQLiteOpenHelper class is not called even though the table doesn't exist

Tags: java, android, sqliteopenhelper

Here is my code:

```
public class ResultDbHandler extends DatabaseHandler {
    private final String TABLE_RESULTS = "results";

    private final String RESULT_ORDER = "order";
    private final String RESULT_PROFILE = "resultProfileId";
    private final String RESULT_FVC = "fvc";
    private final String RESULT_FEV1 = "fev1";
    private final String RESULT_PEV = "pev";
    private final String RESULT_TIME = "time";


    public ResultDbHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        final String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_RESULTS + " ("
                + RESULT_ORDER + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + RESULT_PROFILE + " TEXT, "
                + RESULT_FVC + " REAL, "
                + RESULT_FEV1 + " REAL, "
                + RESULT_PEV + " REAL, "
                + RESULT_TIME + " TEXT, "
                + "FOREIGN KEY(" + RESULT_PROFILE + ") REFERENCES "
                + ProfileDbHandler.TABLE_PROFILES + "(" + ProfileDbHandler.PROFILE_ID + "))";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_RESULTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDbExist() {
        return countRecord() > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int countRecord() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        final String query = "SELECT count(*) FROM " + TABLE_RESULTS;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        int result = cursor.moveToFirst() ? cursor.getInt(0) : 0;
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return result;
    }
```

Anyway, `DatabaseHandler` directly extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Then, I simply call `isDbExist()` right after initializing `dbHandler` object which is like

```
...
dbHandler = new ResultDbHandler(activity);
dbHandler.isDbExist();
...
```

Somehow, the app crashed and the logcat said:

```
09-09 22:34:58.904 4789-4789/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: results
09-09 22:34:58.907 4789-4789/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-09 22:34:58.910 4789-4789/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.kahl.silir, PID: 4789
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kahl.silir/com.kahl.silir.main.history.MeasurementResultActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: results (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT count(*) FROM results
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2526)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:169)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5549)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
                                                  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: results (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT count(*) FROM results
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:898)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:509)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1346)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1285)
                                                     at com.kahl.silir.databasehandler.ResultDbHandler.countRecord(ResultDbHandler.java:64)
                                                     at com.kahl.silir.databasehandler.ResultDbHandler.isDbExist(ResultDbHandler.java:57)
                                                     at com.kahl.silir.main.history.MeasurementResultActivity.onCreate(MeasurementResultActivity.java:54)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2526) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:169) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5549) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

I have no idea why `onCreate` method from `ResultDbHandler` isn't called even though it said the table didn't exist. I've just done the same pattern in another activity using another direct child of `DatabaseHandler`. It works properly. Please kindly explain to me, why could this happen and how to fix it?

Comment: SQLiteOpenHelper does not care about tables, all it cares is database files and versioning of them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run

Comment: so how can I create the table automatically when the constructor is called for the first time only? @laalto

Comment: It's likely you already have a database file with the same name and version, so `onCreate()` or `onUpgrade()` is not triggered. You can uninstall your app to get rid of that database file.

Comment: The code does not show what `DATABASE_NAME` etc. are but is it possible that you're sharing the same database file in more than one `SQLiteOpenHelper`? That would not work.

Comment: Good guess! I already have a database file with the same name and version. I got it, thanks for helping @laalto is there another alternative way to share the same database file?

Comment: Put all your code for the tables in the same database file under the same SQLiteOpenHelper class.